# Is there a distance function on Dyck/Tamari words of arbitrary length?

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Consider sequences of well-formed parentheses (or up/down sequences) of the type counted by the Catalan numbers. See  http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catalan.pdf
These are sometimes called Dyck words or Tamari sequences.  The first several are **()**, **(())**, **()()**, **((()))**, **(()())**, **(())()**, **()(())**, and **()()()**.

For fixed length, these words can be placed in binary trees or associohedra, and  there are distance measurements based on polyhedral geometry and rotation in binary trees:
See https://dx.doi.org/10.1090%2FS0894-0347-1988-0928904-4 and 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6296 and
http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-0405-9

Question: Is there a well-defined distance between words of different length?

E.g., I'd like a distance measurement for which
**()** is closer to **(()())** than to **()()()** because the missing pieces are deeper.  In my context, deeper means smaller.  The distance measurement should reproduce those cited above when the word-lengths match.  I hope that this is possible with discretized hyperbolic geometry or just binary rotations combined with an appropriately weighted Hamming distance.

I'm not terribly familiar with this field and my basic lit search has come up dry.  Has this been studied?

Comment: See chapter 11 of https://books.google.de/books?id=q_7FBAAAQBAJ for a general discussion of distances on words. Also, do you really need a distance or merely a dissimilarity measure?